# switch with loop

Tags: java, eclipse, switch-statement

I am trying to create a loop with the switch statement. If user does not enter between 1 and 4 a message of "You enter incorrect option" keeps re-occurring. I am working on Lynda video. I am not sure where to put the loop. I cannot currently find a way to get it to loop. Is it in the switch or in the getInput method. Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance if anyone knows. I am using eclipse, java 7.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");



  double result = 0;
   do  { 
           String op = getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");
           int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);
           switch (opInt) 
           {
             case 1:
             result = addValues(s1, s2);
             break;
           }
        } while(opInt<1 || opInt >4);
```

EDIT
error message of...

Multiple markers at this line
- opInt cannot be resolved to a 
 variable

- opInt cannot be resolved to a 
  variable

  //I have a method called addValues among other mathematic operators

  ```
  private static double addValues(String s1, String s2)
  throws NumberFormatException {
  double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
  double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);
  double result = d1 + d2;
  return result;
  }

  private static String getInput(String prompt) {
  BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.print(prompt);
  System.out.flush();

  try {
      return stdin.readLine();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
  }
  }
  ```

  **EDIT**
  I am having a problem with the solution given to me by Tal and Quoi. With Quoi I am getting error of opInt cannot be resolved to a variable because and with Tal nothing happens.

So I have done the following...

```
String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
    String op = getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");

//convert opInt into integer
    int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);

    if (opInt <1 || opInt >4) // used a if statement
     {
      getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");
     }

    double result = 0;
    {
         switch (opInt)
         {
           ...........
           ...........
         }
    }
```

With the if statement, the method calls back the switch statement but after selecting the correct option the printline of "You enter incorrect option" and "the answer is 0.0" displays so therefore no calculation is done. I am not sure if this is a simple solution or what?

**EDIT**
I have now attempted to do a while loop outside the switch. What is happening is that what when I select outside of 1 or 4 I am getting a re-ourrance of message of "Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide" regardless if I enter valid option.

```
do 
{
  getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");
 } while (opInt <1 || opInt >4);

    double result = 0;
    {
       switch (opInt)
       {
           case 1:
            result = addValues(s1, s2);
            break;
             ...........
             ...........
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why not to put the `switch` inside a loop?

Comment: @MrSmith42 - I thought I did. I have not been here for a while so I may have missed or something has changed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it around the last getInput call, the one reading the user's option.

LE:

This is what I originally meant.

```
 String s1 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");
 String s2 = getInput("Enter a numeric value: ");

 int opInt = 0;
 do {
   String op = getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide");
   try {
     opInt = Integer.parseInt(op); 
   }catch(Exception e) {
     //whatever you need to do
   }
 } while (opInt < 1 || opInt > 4);

 switch(opInt) [...]
```

What is happening here: user enters the 2 numbers then it will be asked to enter his option until it is between 1 and 4.

Comment: Well, i am kind of confused now by what you want to achieve. Do you want the user to be able to add/ substract etc continuously or you want the user to select once the operation, do the calculus, display the result and exit?

Comment: All the user does is enter value twice then select simple calculation which all work. User has 4 options that is 1- add, 2- subtract, 3 - multiply and 4 - divide. That works fine as well. Now if user enters options less than 1 or more 4 then re-ourrance  message should show from getInput method ("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply, 4=Divide") which I am struggling with. Have I missed out something?

Comment: I did not put the try and catch method. That's fine. Why did you declare int opInt = 0 outside the do while then declare double inside it?

Comment: I am not using any `double` variables in the `while`. Can you elaborate your last comment?

Comment: no but i did because double was used in the private static double multiplyValues method. Thanks George for your time and effort. I did Delphi back in the days when I was at university. Actually I did my final project in Delphi with paradox (I think that was it was). Developing a music store. It is ridiculous application if you compare it today's application, lol, but got good marks.

Comment: DiscoDude, i started my professional life with Delphi. That was some programming language...

Answer (score 2):

Put `switch-case` inside loop.

```
do{
   String op = getInput("Enter 1=Add, 2=Subtract, 3=Multiply,  
       4=Divide");
   int opInt = Integer.parseInt(op);

   switch(opInt){
      case 1: ... break;
      case 2: ... break;
      case 3: ... break;
      case 4: ... break;
   }
}while(opInt<1 || opInt >4);
```

Comment: And then set a boolean variable in each of the cases, so that the while loop knows to end, when one case has been executed.

Comment: @ Chiel92 you mean boolean true / false? If that's what you mean I need to research on this as well.

Comment: @DiscoDude He was trying create a condition for loop with extra boolean value. but it could possible to make a condition without any extra variable.

Comment: @Quoi - I am seeing error of Multiple markers at this line - opInt cannot be resolved to a variable. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't change the opInt variable:

```
while(opInt < 1 || opInt > 4)
{
    switch (opInt)
    {
        case 1:
        break;
        case 2:
        break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: either Tal and Quoi works. with Quoi I am getting error of opInt cannot be resolved to a variable because and with Tal nothing happens. I think its to do with private static String getInput method then again I could be wrong.